# Aptana / Git: How to "forget" unstaged changes

Tags: git, aptana

I'm new to Git,

Made some local changes that I don't want to commit but do want to keep locally. How do I make Git in Aptana "forget" these changes and remove them from the unstaged changes menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git reset
```

or:

```
git reset (filenames)
```

Comment: Not specific to the Aptana git plugin though.

Comment: Is there a specific way to do it within Aptana?

Comment: @AviMeir, I've never used aptana. Unless aptana is doing something very special with the index this should work from the CLI though.